# backreferences in `rename` regex

Tags: sed, vim, regular-expression, rename

I have A LOT of files named "bar_foo.txt" in a directory, and I'd like to rename them to "foo_bar.txt" instead.

In `sed` and `vim` the regex to to this would be something like `'s/\(bar\)_\(foo\)/\2_\1/g'`, backreferencing the search in the replacement.

1. Is there a way to do this with `rename`? I've seen some hacks piping `ls` to `sed` to `bash`, but that's obviously not an amazing way to do it.
2. Are there another tools that does this?
3. Is there a name for the "sed and vim flavour" of regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the `rename` implementation with Perl regexes (as on Debian/Ubuntu/…, or `prename` on Arch Linux), you need `$1` instead of `\1`. Also, no backslashes on capturing parentheses:

```
rename 's/(.*)_(.*)/$2_$1/' *_*
```

If not, you have to implement it yourself.

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in *_* ; do
    left=${file%_*}
    right=${file##*_}
    mv "$file" "$right"_"$left"
done
```

Note: As written, both commands rename `a_b_c` to `c_a_b`. To get `b_c_a`, change the first capture group to `.*?` in the first case, or `%` to `%%` and `##` to `#` in the second one.

Comment: And don't forget that the whole match is `$&` (because `$0` is the program name).

Answer (score 0):

The standard tool that does this is `pax` - though it works better with hardlinks and copies than with direct moves. Of course, all a move is, essentially, is creating a new link and removing an old one.

I prefer to disengage these steps - for a brief while I have two copies of the same tree and can compare and contrast. This is especially important when renaming files dynamically - it is possible that the result of an edit operation on a filename might be identical to an existing linkname, and in that case which file gets the name?

And so to do the thing as asked POSIXly you can do:

```
pax -rwls'|^\(bar\)_\(foo\).txt$|\2_\1.txt|' -s'|.*||' *_*.txt .
```

The results will be separate links to the files in question when you are through. Verify the results are as you like and remove the old ones.

And the `sed`, `vim` regex style is standard [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. With the [util-linux `rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), no, this one only does basic string replacement. With the Perl-based `rename`, yes, see [choroba's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256415).
2. With zsh's [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

   ```
   autoload -U zmv      # put this in your ~/.zshrc
   zmv '(*)_(*).(*)' '${2}_$1.$3'
   zmv -w '*_*.*' '${2}_$1.$3'
   ```

   The two `zmv` invocations above are equivalent. To act in subdirectories as well, you can use `zmv -w '**/*_*.*' '$1/${3}_$2.$4'`
3. Vi(m) and sed use (extensions of) [basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended). See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)